# Button with additional information on icon click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button with info icon on the side like below:

[image]

Ideally when **only the info icon is clicked** it should shows more info about that button

[image]

and when the whole button is clicked it should go to the necessary link.

Here's what I've done so far..
Button A is showing info but not quite what I want.

Button B has the transition and styling that I want, dimmed when hovered, scaled up when hovered on info icon except no info... I'm not sure how can I only show info when I **click** on the icon while still preserving the necessary link on the button

```
<a class="button">
  <span class="title">
  Button A<span class="search"></span></span>
  <span class="info">Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</a><br/><br/>
<a class="button">Button B<span class="search"></span>
</a><br/><br/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cdz0nfu2/2/

Comment: Sounds like an UX fail to me, to be honest. First of all, as a user I don’t normally expect (what looks like) _one_ button to perform two different tasks. Plus, how would I make that extra explanation go away again? Do I click the whole button thing now once to achieve that first, and then make a second click to trigger the real button action …?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152233/button-with-additional-information-on-icon-click#comment83282993_48152233), however, to answer your question, you can use `jQuery` to listen for the info click:

```
$(".button:nth-of-type(2) span").click(function(){
    alert("info clicked"); <-- Show the other info here
})
```